# How do I change where ~ goes on a Google Cloud Platform virtual machine?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

When I run `cd` then `pwd`, I see `/home/xbrandonthaitran` which I believe was created by Google Cloud when I made the VM instance.

When I run `cd` and `pwd`, I would like to see `/home/brandon`.

`/home/brandon` already exists, but I would like it to be my home directory.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The `~` is a bash substitution for $HOME, so

```
export HOME=/home/brandon
```

To make this automatic on login, add it to the file .bashrc in the original home directory.

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work on a specific terminal, but when I log off it goes back to `/home/xbrandonthaitran`. Do you know how to make the change permanent?

Answer (score 0):

**To solve your issue permanently** you can use a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) and the  [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/usermod.8.html) command.

Please have a look at my steps below:

1. create VM instance:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-c --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200701 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
   ```
2. check current location of `HOME` directory:

   ```
   gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-c
   instance-1:~$ cd ~
   instance-1:~$ pwd
   /home/username
   ```
3. edit VM instance and add `Custom metadata`:

   ```
   Key: startup-script
   Value: #! /bin/bash
          sudo usermod -m -d /home/custom_home username
   ```

   > `-d` The user's new login directory.
   > `-m` Move the content of the user's home directory to the new location.

   there's no need to create `/home/custom_home` in advance
4. restart VM instance and check current location of `HOME` directory:

   ```
   gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-c
   instance-1:~$ cd ~
   instance-1:~$ pwd
   /home/custom_home
   ```
5. edit VM instance and remove `Custom metadata`.
6. restart VM instance and check location of `HOME` directory again:

   ```
   gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-c
   instance-1:~$ cd ~
   instance-1:~$ pwd
   /home/custom_home
   ```